# i cannot set the default header using baseRequestOptions after the application is initialized why?

Tags: angular, angular-http

i want to set the user token after the authentication in order to use it in other next requests. i do this :

```
@Injectable() 
export class CustomRequestOptionsService extends BaseRequestOptions {
constructor(private local: LocalStorageService) {
    super();
}
setToken(token: string) {
    this.setAuthorization('token');
    this.local.set("token",token); 
}

private setAuthorization(token: string) {
    this.headers.set( 'Authorization',`Bearer ${token}`);
}
}
```

My component

```
    register() {
        this.userService.register(this.user).subscribe((response: any) => {
            if (response.token) {
                this.options.setToken(response.token); // i set the token here
                return this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            }
        });

}
```

After this, i make another request using the Authorization Header. But the header doesn't contains the authorization header and the token. Why ???

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the providers to provide your custom class for the RequestOptions.

```
providers: [
    { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: CustomRequestOptionsService }
  ]
```

Have a look at the following article:
https://blog.alex-miller.co/angular/2017/05/13/default-headers-in-angular.html